# How can I diagnose this critical error? Zend_Db and PHPUnit

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit, zend-db

I have an action in a model that adds a record to a table.  It works fine when I test it by typing values in to the browser, but is failing when I test it with PHPUnit.  The frustrating part is that I don't really know how to diagnose the problem.

The unit test has a (rather long) $data array, and the problem occurs when I call the dbTable->insert($data) method.  The log shows:

```
CRIT (2): Application Error
CRIT (2): Request Parameters
```

How can I get more information on these errors?  The line following the offending line is not executed.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to get a more verbose error? I'm getting similarly terse errors, and it's not helpful in the least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I had a boolean field in the DB that was not nullable.  It showed a default value of 0, so I assumed that I didn't need to provide this field in the insert statement. Seems I was wrong.

As soon as I provided a value for this field it worked fine.

Something else that confused this issue is that I had assumed I'd get a more descriptive error in my log if was such a simple error ...